# HSQL Procedure returning result set from declared table

Tags: hsqldb

I created a stored procedure in HSQLDB. I declared a table object and inserted data in to it.How can i pass this all table data from this procedure to caller end,Which is normal java CallebleStatement.

Answer (score 2):

After inserting the data, you write `DECLARE CURSOR ...` then `OPEN ...` statements. See the Guide, http://hsqldb.org/doc/2.0/guide/sqlroutines-chapt.html#src_psm_cursors which contains this example:

```
BEGIN ATOMIC
  DECLARE temp_zero DATE;
  DECLARE result CURSOR WITH RETURN FOR SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES FOR READ ONLY;
  -- more statements ...
  OPEN result;
END
```